# How to fix Azure ml model deployment Error

Tags: python, dependencies, random-forest, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to deploy a RandomForest model using azure ML with ACI , but after i deploy my service i keep getting this error :

```
Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.scriptrun = azureml.core.script_run:ScriptRun._from_run_dto with exception (cryptography 2.9.2 (/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('cryptography>=3.3.1; extra == "crypto"'), {'PyJWT'}).*
```

Here's a snapshot of the code and the error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbhDT.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llrGg.png)
Can you please tell me what should i do to fix this?

Comment: You can refer to similar issues: [Azureml-core dependencies incompatible in latest release 1.23.0](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1370)

Comment: [Don't post images of code and error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3750257)